# OSError: port/proto not found in for loop

Tags: python, sockets, for-loop, network-programming

I wrote a python script using the socket module, which provides getservbyport for retrieving a service name based on a port number argument.

I used the following code:

```
import socket
socket.getservbyport(443) # 'https'
```

But with certain port numbers i'm getting the following error:

```
socket.getservbyport(675)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    socket.getservbyport(675)
OSError: port/proto not found
```

Can someone explain to me why i am getting this error?

Also i want to list the services with their matching port, so I eliminated the errors using `try` and `except` method like the following code:

```
for i in range(0,65536,1):
    try:
        print(i,"Runs, service:",socket.getservbyport(i))
    except:
        continue
```

I'm getting the ports which have a service, but I want to list the serial numbers before the port numbers. Since I used `except` method the errors are eliminated so I can't number them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `OSError: port/proto not found` is thrown when no service is found on that port. So if you're iterating through all possible ports, odds are you will almost certainly get that error. Catching the error is the right way to go.

To achieve what you need, use a separate counter to keep track of the number of services found:

```
counter = 1
for i in range(0, 65536):
    try:
        service = socket.getservbyport(i)
        print(counter, " port nr ", i, " runs service ", service)
        counter += 1
    except:
        continue
```

Alternatively if you would like the services data elsewhere, store the services in-order in an array, like so:

```
services = []
for i in range(0, 65536):
    service = None
    try:
        service = socket.getservbyport(i)
    except:
        pass
    if service is not None:
        services += [{'service': service, 'port': i}]

for idx, s in enumerate(services):
    print(idx, " port nr ", s['port'], " runs service ", s['service'])
```

Comment: Elwin Arens, Thanks for the suggestion but what if I just want to list only the **Service Running** port numbers with the serial numbers, Because it is unnecessary if I just list **No service ports** I just want to know what are the ports running with the services with the numbers too is there any other way through which I can achieve that?

Comment: And yes I understand about the range default step size, Its my regular way of coding to add step up value even its 1, better I would try to change that habit too. Thanks

Comment: @Sundararajan A port number is not a unique identification number for a type of service, although ports below 1024 are generally reserved for common services, such as http, https, ftp etc. Basically any service could be bound to the same port so for example getservbyport(8000) could return different values on different systems.

Comment: @Sundararajan You're using a mix of port, port number, serial numbers and services, which is very confusing. A port may have a service running. That's all there is. Could you write down what it is exactly you're trying to achieve? If you can't put it in words properly, try showing it in code.

Comment: Yes, you are right I understand that, but my query is I want to list the answer like this,
1 Port No:7 Runs service:Some service
2 Port No:10 Runs service:Some other Service
3 Port No: 13 Runs service:Another Service

Now the you can see that 1,2,3 are the continuous numbers even though the port Numbers are skipped from 7 to 10 and 10 to 13 

How can I achieve this so that I can exactly see the number of services running by point by points

Comment: `1 Port No:7 Runs service:Some service`
`2 Port No:10 Runs service:Some other Service`
`3 Port No: 13 Runs service:Another Service`

This is how I want to list the ports with numbers **1,2,3** till the last port so that I can see the number of ports or services available by checking the last number but using port No i cant achieve because it may skip some ports due to my continue statement

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem of
`OSError: port/proto not found`
by adding the tcp protocol like this

```
import socket
print(socket.getservbyport(22, "tcp"))
```